# Loop only deletes first file

Tags: java, file, delete-file

I'm having a problem getting all the selected files deleted. What I'm trying to do is after clicking "Add"  whatever files are selected are moved to a new folder and are deleted in their previous folder. One file works fine. It deletes and moves the file. But more than one and only the first gets deleted. My loop is recognizing each file just not deleting them. I'm posting the actionevent. If more code is needed let me know. I've indicated where the problem is, so I think, so you don't have to search the code.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int returnValue = 0;
    int option = 0;
    File[] selectedFiles = new File[0];

    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("CLOSE")) System.exit(0);

    else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("ADD")) {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        returnValue = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);         

        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

            File[] file = chooser.getSelectedFiles();                   

            try {
                FileInputStream fstream = null;
                FileOutputStream ostream = null;

                for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {

                   fstream = new FileInputStream(file[i]);
                           ostream = new      
                                       FileOutputStream(file[i].getName());

                    Path path = Paths.get(file[i].getPath());
                    byte[] fileArray;
                    fileArray = Files.readAllBytes(path);

                    listModel.add(0, file[i].getName());
                    selectedFilesList.setModel(listModel);
                                  //ostream.write(fileArray, 0, fileArray.length);

                }

                fstream.close();
                //ostream.close();

                try {

                    for(int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
//**----------------------->>>PROBLEM**                     
                    Files.delete(Paths.get(file[i].getPath()));
                    System.out.println(file[i].getName());

                    }


                } catch (NoSuchFileException x) {}
        System.err.format("%s: no such" + " file or directory%n")
                } catch (DirectoryNotEmptyException x) {
                    System.err.format("%s not empty%n");
                } catch (IOException x) {
                    // File permission problems are caught here.
                    System.err.println(x);
                } catch (Exception err) {
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you seeing any evidence of exceptions? Also, your `catch` clauses for `IOException` and especially `Exception` are rather stingy in their output. A stack trace would be more helpful than just a string representation of the exception (or nothing!).

Comment: not getting any exceptions. It runs and if I sysout the filename it shows the 3 files selected but when try to delete only the first goes.

Comment: What system are you on, what java version, and are the files located on a network share? I just recently read about a bug concerning older java versions on windows where file descriptors weren't properly released when the files resided on a network drive.

Comment: How can you be sure you don't get any exception? You just handle NoSuchFileException, DirectoryNotEmptyException, and IOException. The catch block for Execption is empty. I'm sure something is thrown...

Comment: Windows 7 JDK 1.7 files are on my computer. Just moving from folder to folder

Comment: Hm... SecurityException is a candidate, as well as anything derived from RuntimeException...

Comment: What happens if you attach a debugger at the line above where you have a problem? What is the length of the array "file"? And what are the values inside the array?

Comment: the length of the array is how many files are selected and files are whats in the array

Comment: also why is it then it works with one file but not many? I'm going to try closing the streams inside the loop as David Waters suggested. That seems to make a lot of sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be caused by you failing to close your file streams in the first loop.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
               fstream = new FileInputStream(file[i]);
                       ostream = new      
                                   FileOutputStream(file[i].getName()); // This is never closed

                Path path = Paths.get(file[i].getPath());
                byte[] fileArray;
                fileArray = Files.readAllBytes(path);

                listModel.add(0, file[i].getName());
                selectedFilesList.setModel(listModel);
                              //ostream.write(fileArray, 0, fileArray.length);

            }

            fstream.close();  // Only the last input stream is closed
```

should be more like

```
            for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
              try {
                 fstream = new FileInputStream(file[i]);
                 ostream = new      
                      FileOutputStream(file[i].getName());

                  Path path = Paths.get(file[i].getPath());
                  byte[] fileArray;
                  fileArray = Files.readAllBytes(path);

                  listModel.add(0, file[i].getName());
                  selectedFilesList.setModel(listModel);
                  //ostream.write(fileArray, 0, fileArray.length);
               } finally {
                 fstream.close();
                 ostream.close();
               }
            }
```

Closing the same number of files you open.

This could be causing your problem by holding a lock on all but one of your files which would prevent deletion.

Also your catch exception block (last statement) does nothing with the error.

Comment: I had them both closed. But it behaved the same. But I'll try your way. As for the last exception; The application seems to be running just not executing the full loop thats why I didn't bother with the last exception block because I've tried a thousand things to get this to work and exceptions weren't being thrown

Comment: It needs to be inside the loop. Your code sample has both fstream and ostream being closed only once yet opening multiple files. Like that the close would only effect the most recent file.

Answer (score 3):

Don't move files like that!

1. If you are on Java 7, have at look at this [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html) instead.
2. For older versions, use [`oldFile.renameTo(newFile)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29).

EDIT: To understand why your code is not working, use a debugger. I would think your deletion loop is left because of an exception.

Comment: nice. I was unaware of that. But would that have something to do with why all the files aren't being moved